# Access attributes of objects in a list

Tags: python

I'm using a book called *Python for Absolute Beginners* and am doing a challenge in the book's chapter 8 (*Software Objects*). My  code works but I want to add another capability to the code; What code do I need to add to feed/play/talk with a specific critter?

In choice #7 of my code (*7 - Feed a specific critter*), I have written some code but it doesn't work. How might I access/change the attributes of a specific object that the user selects?

Also, any feedback to improve/shorten the code?

```
# Critter Caretaker
# A virtual pet to care for
class Critter(object):
    import random
    """A virtual pet"""
    def __init__(self, name, hunger = random.randint(0,9), boredom = random.randint(0,11)):
        self.name = name
        self.hunger = hunger
        self.boredom = boredom

    def __pass_time(self):
        self.hunger +=1
        self.boredom +=1

    def __str__(self):

        m = "name is: {}, hunger is: {}, boredom is: {}".format(self.name, self.hunger,self.boredom)


        return m

    @property
    def mood(self):
        unhappiness = self.hunger + self.boredom
        if unhappiness <5:
            m = "happy"
        elif 5 <= unhappiness <=10:
            m = "okay"
        elif 11 <= unhappiness <=15:
            m = "frustrated"
        else:
            m= "mad"
        return m

    def talk(self):
        print("I'm", self.name, "and I feel", self.mood, "now.\n")
        self.__pass_time()

    def eat(self, food=3):
        print("Yummy! Thank you.")
        self.hunger -=food
        if self.hunger <0:
            self.hunger = 0
        self.__pass_time()

    def play(self, fun=4):

        print("That was fun! Thanks")
        self.boredom -=fun
        if self.boredom <0:
            self.boredom = 0
        self.__pass_time()

def main():
    noc = []
    noc.append(Critter("Chicken"))
    print("An critter named Chicken has been created")
    choice = None
    while choice != "0":
        print \
        ("""
        Critter Caretaker

        0 - Quit
        1 - Listen to all your critters
        2 - Feed all your critters
        3 - Play with all your critters
        4 - Create a new critter
        5 - Show a list of critters
        6 - Delete a critter
        7 - Feed a specific critter
        """)

        choice = input("Choice: ")
        print()

        # exit
        if choice == "0":
            print("Good-bye.")

        # listen to critters
        elif choice == "1":
            if len(noc) != 0:
                i.talk()
            else:
                print("No critters exist")
        # feed your critters
        elif choice == "2":
            if len(noc) != 0: 
                for i in noc:
                    print(i.name, "says:", end = " ")
                    i.eat()
        # play with your critters
        elif choice == "3":
            if len(noc) != 0: 
                for i in noc:
                    print(i.name, "says:", end = " ")
                    i.play()
            else:
                print("No critter exists")
        # Create a new critter
        elif choice == "4":
            noc.append(Critter(input("Enter a name for your new critter: ")))
        # Show critters
        elif choice =="5":
            b = 0
            if len(noc) != 0: 
                for i in noc:
                    b +=1
                    print(b, "." ,i.name)
            else:
                print("No critter exists")
        # delete a critter
        elif choice == "6":
            a = int(input("Enter the serial number of critter you want to delete: "))
            a = a -1
            del noc[a]

        # feed a specific critter
        elif choice == "7":
            sctd = input("Enter name of critter you want to feed: ")
            if sctd in noc:
                noc.eat()
            else:
                print("That critter doesn't exists")


        # print attributes of critters
        elif choice == "919":
            for i in noc:
                print(i)
        else:
            print("\nSorry, but", choice, "isn't valid.")

main()
("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the branch for feeding a specific critter, you have the line `noc.eat()` -- `noc` is a list, which has no `eat()` method. You need to access the critter specified by the input, and call the `eat()` method on that object. Something like:

```
for c in noc:
    if c.name == sctd:
        c.eat()
        break
```

(although there is an issue with this example if multiple critters match `sctd` -- solving that is something i'll leave to you)

an additional minor point of feedback on your code: a docstring should be the first statement inside the definition as per [PEP 0257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring).

Answer (score 0):

Just a small note is that I think the convention something like `import random` should probably be placed at the start rather than inside the class which also gets rid of the problem raised by @nthall which is that your docstring is currently not the first object.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). Or perhaps you want to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)?

Comment: I was not asking a question I was merely being slightly vague because I was only 90% sure on the python norms about this issue.